# BecomeFirstResponder for uitextfiled not working only for the first time alone when the view is pushed

Tags: ios

```
Here is my code:

**MoreViewController.m**
```

From this view am calling another view controller FansLoyalityViewController

```
FansLoyalityViewController *fans = [[FansLoyalityViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FansLoyalityViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] ];
        fans.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
        fans.title=title;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:fans animated:YES];

**FansLoyalityViewController.m** 

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
    [firstName becomeFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:NO];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];    
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

My problem is same code working fine in English language am getting keypad on uitextfield for first time working perfectly good..But i used Localization and changed the language to arabic..Only after changed to arabic am getting this problem "Cursor blinking but keypad is hidden for first time and if i move back and view this page again am getting the keypad"

Only for the first time when the view appears keypad is not shown that too when the language is changed to arabic

I also reffered this links:
[Cursor is blinking in UITextField but keyboard doesn't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960410/cursor-is-blinking-in-uitextfield-but-keyboard-doesnt-appear)
    [Adding [myUITextField becomeFirstResponder]; does not bring up keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221601/adding-myuitextfield-becomefirstresponder-does-not-bring-up-keyboard).

I am newbie to ios.So please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You should call [firstName becomeFirstResponder] after [super viewWillAppear:animated].

Comment: I called [firstName becomeFirstResponder] after [super viewWillAppear:animated] already then also its not worked.In English version its working the same code but in arabic version am not getting.